# Is .profile read upon GUI login

Tags: command-line, .profile

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile), it is mentioned that there is no standard behavior in terms of whether `.profile` is read or not when a user logs in from the GUI in today's Linux and Unix systems. So for Ubuntu, is `.profile` read when I log in from the GUI?

On a somewhat unrelated note, is there a way to log in to Ubuntu locally via the terminal only (i.e. not using GUI and not using SSH to remote it)?

Comment: Rename (`mv`) the file and relogin and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoted from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4-.2F.profile

> ~/.profile
>
> In this file you can also place environment variable assignments,
> since it gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the
> start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when
> one logs in from the textual console. This is a ~/.profile equivalent
> of the above example:
>
> export FOO=bar
> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/MyPrograms"
> Note: The code in
> ~/.profile is run after ~/.pam_environment has been read. That makes
> ~/.profile suitable to use if you want to override a locale related
> variable that was set in ~/.pam_environment via e.g. Language Support.

**It gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the
start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when
one logs in from the textual console.**

This means that either GUI or CLI will read and use `.profile`

> Is there a way to log in to Ubuntu locally via the terminal only

The answer is sure. you can either use:

- Virtual terminals(consoles) tty[1..6]
- Booting in text mode

#### Virtual terminals(consoles) tty[1..6]

To use tty[1..6] just press the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1..6]</kbd>

*PS: tty[1..6] = tty1 ,tty2, ... tty6*

#### To boot into true text mode

Edit in /etc/default/grub

**Stops the Ubuntu splash**

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

**Uncomment to disable graphical terminal by removing the leading hash #**

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Then update your grub to load the new configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```